# How to retrieve a value off a webite using python

Tags: python, html

I was wondering if there was anyway to make a python script to take a said value from a website, in my case a offline number that is on a website that refreshes every 5 minutes. I would like to have it set up if that value increases it would send me an email. Reason I am wanting to do this is because I work at a bitcoin mining facility that has over 15,000 miners and we have to monitor them constantly. But carrying around a laptop while performing daily tasks such as cleaning and things of that nature is very aggravating and annoying. I know very little about python so if someone could point me in the right direction I would greatly appreciate it. . I am trying to pull get just the offline number from this part of the html source code  [screenshot of the source code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8ztq.png).........I am trying to use the Xpath of the part that I am needing, for all I know I might be doing it wrong. Any and all advice would be greatly appreciated. Reminder I am really new to python.

```
from lxml import html
import requests
import time

page = requests.get('***')

tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
number = tree.xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div[4]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/a/span//*')

print(number)
```

But when I run the code this is what I am getting..

[ ]

[Finished in 2.062s]

Answer (score 0):

use [selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/) in `python` to scrape every web attributes and get their values or whatever your company asks you to do. this is a very good practice to start web scraping with python and creating bots. check out this code block to get the `span` tag value in selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("your_url")
driver.find_element_by_class_name("box-bottom-offline").get_attribute("innerHTML")
```

Of course, there are many other libraries. but selenium is topping the bills

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\byteb\Desktop\Pi Programs\url4.py", line 2, in <module>

    driver = webdriver.Chrome()

  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 81, in start
    raise WebDriverException(
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home

Comment: That is what I received tryin that ?

Comment: first of all. download chrome driver from http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads and it has to be located in your PATH system environment variable

Comment: I tried this but I dont think it's going to to work because when you first log onto the website you have to enter your email and password along with a captcha text, then you receive a 6 digit verification code via text to put in to be able to log on.